# Exported objects are giving undefined when passed via call() to another exported function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have my utils.js as follows:

```
//utils.js
"use strict"
export const eng = {
   val: 'Love'
}

export const spanish = {
   val: 'Amo'
}
export const showMe = ()=>{
   console.log(this.val);
}
```

Now I am using these exported variables and function in another file as follows:

```
//main.js
import {eng, spanish, showMe} from "/utils";

const fn = () => {
   showMe.call(eng); //here eng has correct value
}
```

Upon invoking fn(), I am receving value of `this` inside showMe() in utils.js as undefined. I am new to js and not really able to find any relevant material explaining this issue. Any pointers?

Comment: `this` in your utils.js's `showMe` function is "whatever it is at runtime", which is kind of a weird thing to do, but even weirder if it's code you're writing because you're new to JS: did something teach you that this was how you should be writing JS?

Comment: You should definitely just be passing `eng` as a normal argument and then using `env.val` inside the fn.

Comment: Since I am supplying object to showMe() inside fn(), I thought it will behave similar to how it is when showMe() is not an arrow function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Arrow functions, by definition, [do not support `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions). You need a standard function to use `this`, even with `.call`.

```js
export function showMe() {
   console.log(this.val);
}
```